# Handling of requests with Header Accept-Encoding in CloudFront vs request without the header Accept-Encoding

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloud Front Distribution to cache  my images. my origin server is NOT S3, its some server i run.

I use these images in my website(taking the advantage of CF caching). Now to explain the problem, lets assume in my home page i am using an image called `banner.png`.

I visit my home page lets say from chrome for the first time - for banner.png its a cache miss, so it gets fetched fro origin and cached in CF.

After this i visit my page from FF,opera, Chromium, GET "banner.png" using postman - `this all gets me the file from CF cache`.

Now i GET  "banner.png" using insomnia (Another rest client) - `Now CF doesn't send me from cache, it goes back to origin to get the image, and reply me with **"x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront"**`.

the difference between these 2 sets of clients are first set of clients sends **"Accept-Encoding: gzip"** header in the request and second client did not.

in my CF behaviour -

> "Cache Based on Selected Request Headers" = NONE
>
> Objects Automatically" = NO"Compress

.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront keeps two different copies of cache based on Accept-encoding.

1. One if Header contains Accept-encoding: gzip
2. Accept-encoding: any other value or without the header.

You can test it using curl, first without accept-encoding and second request with accept-encoding: gzip and you'll see MISS from CloudFront, this is expected with CloudFront.

The reason being is that CloudFront supports only gzip compression and it keeps this header into consideration to know if it needs to compress the response or not.

However, Your problem seems different, You're seeing Refersh from CloudFront which happens when CloudFront TTLs/Max-age expires and CloudFront is making a Condition GET to the origin to know if the content has been modified or not.
Ideally, it should be a Miss From CloudFront if no accept-header is present.

Comment: I dont have to test with curl. i already did - one with few browsers & other with insomnia and result is mentioned in my question itself. Regarding the last part about the refresh - i dont see a refresh and it has nothing todo with TTL or max-age. My problem is  even if i have "No Compress" in my CF behavior, it keeps 2 copies based on Accept-encoding, and how can i make CF not do that

Comment: You can't prevent it, it's the behavior or CloudFront even you don't have compress enabled and if you don't see Refershhit, don't mentioned it in description.